# App icons semi missing on MBPTB 2016

Tags: mac, applications

I'm trying to figure out why sometimes my icons don't display properly on my Late 2016 MBP with TouchBar.

It happened back when I was on Sierra and now on High Sierra as well.

It seems that they only revert to the default app icon in the dock, but most of the time the app icon really does show up in mission control.

[image: This is the Dock where you can see that some app icons have reverted to the default image. Note that the app the the mouse is over is the siri app.]

[image: And here you can see that the slack app on the dock does not have the right app icon, but in mission control it does.]

Any ideas as to why this might be happening are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by the League of Legend updater.

The bug has been reported few months ago in [Riot forums](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bug-report/rA0p1rYx-client-updating-on-mac-high-sierra-messes-up-other-application-icons), but they do not seem to care about it.

> Any time I download an update, it causes other applications on my Mac to have their icons go missing (most notable in the dock area). This has been happening on both High Sierra and Sierra before it for a long time.

However, you'll see on the forum that somebody posted a temporary fix which consists in running a shell script after each game update.

> To recap on the previous comment I made, [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/Etheryte/d74cbd9c37b59b49c25a0c6121507fd5) seems to do the job, for the time being.
>   I'm not going to note down how to run it since if you don't know, you probably shouldn't be running scripts from the internet.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think I'd get an answer to this! Thank you so much. It hasn't been as bad lately, so maybe they've got a fix in place now? Anyway, if it happens again, I'm glad I have a fix now! Thanks!